# is_nothrow_xxxable vs. is_nothrow_move/copy_xxxable

Tags: c++, c++11

I noticed there are such three type traits in the standard library:

```
std::is_nothrow_constructible       // (1)
std::is_nothrow_copy_constructible  // (2)
std::is_nothrow_move_constructible  // (3)
```

There meanings of (2)(3) are clear from their names, but what does (1) actually mean? Is it a logical AND of (2)(3), a logical OR of (2)(3), or something else?

Similarly, we can replace `nothrow` with `trivially` and `constructible` with `assignable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is_constructible`, `is_nothrow_constructible`, and `is_trivially_constructible` are for asking if the type can be constructed from a sequence of arguments. Obviously, the `nothrow` and `trivially` versions add additional requirements on the selected constructor. They're variadic; `is_copy/move_constructible` are not.

So it's not the same thing. The plain `constructible` versions are more or less a functional superset of the more focused `copy/move` versions. Indeed, the others are (mostly) defined in terms of the `constructible` forms.

Comment: Oh I see. The no copy/move version is more like `is_constructible_from` then.

Comment: `is_constructible` and the others are not variadic. The list of arguments to be used to test them is variadic. You still have to test a type at a time anyway.